# WWDCのセッション番号の規則

Tags: apple

WWDC2016のセッション一覧
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2016/

これを見ると、セッション番号が100番台ずつ区切られているようですが、これはどういう規則で分別されているのでしょうか？
日付？扱うテクノロジー？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

扱う技術によって分類されています。

200番台は「App Frameworks」、400番台は「Developer Tools」、800番台は「Design」という風な分類です。

ビデオをスクロールして"All Videos"以降を見ていくと、区切りに薄いグレーの帯があり、どの技術かというのが上記のようなタイトルで示されています。

Comment: それ見逃してました。ありがとうございます。